# Error while starting spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

While i'm trying to start a spring boot app and i got an error caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/WritableEnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.WritableEnvironmentEndpoint]: Factory method 'environmentEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 26
.*PropertiesPropertySource {name='management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize'}$
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/WritableEnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.WritableEnvironmentEndpoint]: Factory method 'environmentEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 26
.*PropertiesPropertySource {name='management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize'}$
```

Comment: { is an indicator to the regex engine that you are about to start a repetition indicator, like {2,4}

Answer (score 0):

try removing
***Spring Cloud Services Starter Circuit Breaker*** dependency
or

```
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
```